# ERROR when referencing foreign key in table

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys

Im getting this error when creating a table "Oracle (ORA-02270) : no matching unique or primary key for this column-list error".
This is the first time creating tables, but Ive created a table let say customer order, which has a primary key of customer id and product Id.

```
create table customer_order(
    customerID NUMBER(8),
    productID Number(8),
    PRIMARY KEY (customerID, productID),
    FOREIGN KEY (customerID) REFERENCES Customer (customerID),
    FOREIGN KEY (productID) REFERENCES Product (productID));
```

So this the table i orginially created, however i need to create a new table that references the customer ID and product ID from this table. When I do so I get this error. Here is an example of the table I'm trying to create:

```
create table purchase_order(
    ID Number(8) PRIMARY KEY,
    ProductId Number(8),
    CustomerID Number(8),
    FOREIGN KEY (customerID) REFERENCES customer_order (customerID),
    FOREIGN KEY (productID) REFERENCES customer_order (productID));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary key is *composite*, so you need to reference them at the same time:

```
create table purchase_order(
    ID Number(8) PRIMARY KEY,
    ProductId Number(8),
    CustomerID Number(8),
    FOREIGN KEY (customerID, ProductId) REFERENCES customer_order(customerID, productId)
);
```